# use negative lookahead assertion to extract duplicated part in file names

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use "negative lookahead assertion" of Python re module to extract the duplicated file names. For example, I have a number of files with same basic names but different ending numbers to tell them apart, like:

```
abc.txt
abc 1.txt
abc 2.txt
..
abc 45.txt
```

in which abc could be anything, including spaces, but not ending with numbers. I am going to extract abc from these filenames so I can know they in one group.

I have tried to use negative lookahead assertion like below:

`re.search(r"((?:(?! \d\.).)*?)", filename)`

but got a bunch of empty strings, representing the middle of each consecutive characters, rather than 'abc'. Something wrong?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You are misusing the lookahead. Just use `re.sub(r'\d+\.\w+$', '', s).rstrip()`

Comment: That's a cleaner and helpful way. If you could post it as an answer, I will mark it. At the mean time, can u comment on why my original way doesn't do the job? thx.

Comment: If you want to use a lookahead, you should use a positive one that asserts that the characters following the capture are an optional space and digits, followed by the file extension e.g. `re.search(r'^.*?(?=(\s*\d+)?\.\w+$)', name).group(0)`

Comment: What are you using to write your regex?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `((?:(?! \d\.).)*?)` pattern matches any char other than a line break char, 0 or more occurrences but as few as possible, that does not start a space+digit+dot character sequence. When used in `re.search`, it just finds the first occurrence at the start of a string.

Since you want to find a common prefix, you may just remove the unnessary suffix:

```
result = re.sub(r'\s*\d*\.\w+$', '', filename).rstrip()
```

Here, `\s*\d*\.\w+$` will find 0 or more whitespaces, then 0 or more digits, a dot and any 1+ word chars at the end of the string, and `re.sub` will remove the found match.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CeP1AH/1).